# Function composition chain using method

Tags: java, lambda

How Should I declare method combine which can take arguments in such a way:

```
Function<List<String>,String> f1;
Function<String,List<Integer>> f2;
Function<List<Integer>,Integer> f3;

System.out.println(this.combine(f1));
System.out.println(this.combine(f1,f2));
System.out.println(this.combine(f1,f2,f3));
etc
```

this is a generic object with parameter indicating what type of objects it contains, in above example it is a list of string

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question does not clearly state what output you expect from your method for a given input - like that it is hard to help you. Please provide an example for input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you are right. Method combine should return value of last function, so:

```
Obj obj = new Obj(Arrays.asList(args));
String s = obj.combine(f1);
List<Integer> l = obj.combine(f1,f2);
Integer i = obj.combine(f1,f2,f3)
```

You can't overload combine method